# SharedPreferences.Editor for RadioButton in RadioGroup

Tags: android, radio-button, sharedpreferences

How to use shared preferences for radio button in radio group.  I have two buttons (next and previous).

I want to check the user selected option when user goes to next and came to previous again that time.

I tried like this it throws error. What mistake in doing?

Thanks a lot in advance.

> ```
>      ImageView nextBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nxt_btn);
>         nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
>         public void onClick(View v){
>         btn_practice1.setChecked(false);
>         btn_practice2.setChecked(false);
>         btn_practice3.setChecked(false);
>         btn_practice4.setChecked(false);
>   btn_practicerg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
>     @Override
>       public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) { 
>       RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)group. findViewById(checkedId);                    
>       int checkedIndex = group.indexOfChild(radioButton);
>       getSharedPreferences(KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX, checkedIndex);                                             
>       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
>       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
>       editor.putInt("check", checkedIndex);
>       editor.commit(); 
>     });
>  });
>    ImageView previousbtn1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.prv_btn);
>        previousbtn1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
>        public void onClick(View v){
>        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
>        int savedRadioIndex = sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX, 0);
>        RadioButton savedCheckedRadioButton = (RadioButton)group.getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);  //  line number  570                         
>        savedCheckedRadioButton.setChecked(true);
>   });
> ```

LogCat

> ```
>       E/AndroidRuntime(362): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
>       E/AndroidRuntime(362): java.lang.NullPointerException
>       E/AndroidRuntime(362): at 
>       com.example.TEENEINSTIEN.Question$LoadQuestions$4.onClick(Question.java:570)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(362): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(362): at 
>       android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(362): at 
>       android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(362): at 
>       android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(362): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(362): at 
>       android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(362): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native 
>       Method)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(362): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(362): at 
>       com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(362): at 
>       com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(362): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

Comment: which line of your code shows error.

Comment: i have mentioned in my code line number 570 the above line

Comment: But we can't count your line number. so show which is 570 line number

Comment: @Nirali code contains the comment line showing `// throws error line number 570`

Comment: Did you log `savedRadioIndex` to check whether you're getting the required value or not ?

Comment: yes i log im getting the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `group` is invissible or didn't assigned properly in your `previousbtn1.setOnClickListener()`. Try to use `RadioGroup myradioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);` in your `previousbtn1.setOnClickListener()`.

```
 btn_practicerg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) { 
      RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)group. findViewById(checkedId);                    
      int checkedIndex = group.indexOfChild(radioButton);
     // getSharedPreferences(KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX, checkedIndex);                                             
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
      editor.putInt("check", checkedIndex);
      editor.commit(); 
    });
 });
   ImageView previousbtn1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.prv_btn);
       previousbtn1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
       public void onClick(View v){
       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
       int savedRadioIndex = sharedPreferences.getInt("check", 0);
       System.out.println("savedRadioIndex is "+savedRadioIndex);
       RadioGroup myradioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
       RadioButton savedCheckedRadioButton = (RadioButton)myradioGroup.getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);
                             // throws error line number 570
       savedCheckedRadioButton.setChecked(true);
  });
```

Try this way. I hope this will help you.

Comment: error is in this line 'RadioButton savedCheckedRadioButton = (RadioButton)group.getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);'

Comment: Try this way. And tell me what happens? and kindly provide your radio group id `findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);` here.

Comment: No it throws the same error only.. what mistake im doing i don't know

Comment: i have used like this `int checkedId = group.indexOfChild(radioButton);
     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
     int savedRadioIndex = GetSet.getValue();
      System.out.println("savedradioIndex" + savedRadioIndex);
      
      RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)group. findViewById(checkedId); 
      RadioButton savedCheckedRadioButton = (RadioButton)group.getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);                 
          savedCheckedRadioButton.setChecked(true);`

Comment: I have checked the answer when means if i came previous its clear and if i select some other option means that time old one is checked...refer my code here http://pastie.org/8003622